# Why does this work in one place and not the other?

Tags: swift

I have two instances of almost the same code, one works and the other doesn’t.

Working through Apple’s Intro to App Development with Swift I’ve reached a point where I’m supposed to make an array, write a function that gives at least two responses to the data in the array, and then write a `for...in` loop that goes through it and gives the correct response to each value in the array. I keep getting this error:

> Binary operator ‘>=‘ cannot be applied to two ‘[Int]’ operands error.

But, if I put the `for...in` loop inside the function everything works.

```
func goal(time:[Int]) {
    for code in time {
        if (code >= 90) {
            print ("Good Bunny, Have a carrot!")
        }else {
            print ("Bad Rabbit! Try Harder!")
        }
    }
}

goal(time: codeLearned)


func bunny(bun: [Int]){
    if (bun >= [90]) {
        print ("Good Bunny")
    } else {
        print ("Bad Rabbit")
    }
}
bunny(bun: codeLearned)
```

With the function that contains the loop, putting the `if` in brackets `()` fixed the error, but that isn’t working without the loop, and since the exercise is to do it without the loop that’s what I want to do.

Comment: It is not “almost the same” code. Your first example compares two integers. The second example compares two *arrays of integers* (which does not work).

Comment: If I change [90] to 90 I get : binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type [Int] and Int. If I then change [Int] in the function row to Int, I get the error: Cannot convert value of type [Int] to expected argument type “Int”.

Comment: Of course, because `bun` (your parameter) is an array of int. You could for instance compare `bun[0] >= 90`, which whould take the first element of the `bun` array and compares it to your value. Or (I don't know your assigment) you could change your `bun` to be an `Int` and not an `[Int]`

Comment: That worked, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have the same logic. The first function checks the value of the element in the array, the second tries to compare the given array with a single-element array.

```
func goal(time:[Int]) {
    for code in time {
        if (code >= 90) {
            print ("Good Bunny, Have a carrot!")
        } else {
            print ("Bad Rabbit! Try Harder!")
        }
    }
}

goal(time: codeLearned)


/// If your goal is the check count of array 
func bunny(bun: [Int]){
    if (bun.count >= 90) {
        print ("Good Bunny")
    } else {
        print ("Bad Rabbit")
    }
}
bunny(bun: codeLearned)

/// If your goal is the check element value in array
func bunny(bun: [Int]){
    for item in bun { 
        if (item >= 90) {
            print ("Good Bunny")
        } else {
            print ("Bad Rabbit")
        }       
    }
}
bunny(bun: codeLearned)
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.